# How to find all records which are NOT in this array? (MySql)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, database

I have an array which contains a bunch of ID:s...

I can't figure out how to write a query for finding all records which are NOT inside this array, in mysql.

```
    SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE ..........
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
$str = implode(',', $your_array);
```

The above statements converts an array into comma-delimited string.

```
"SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE id NOT IN ('$str')"
```

**More Info:**

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Comment: Little tweak: `$str = count($your_array) != 0 ? implode(',', $your_array); : "null";`. `IN` doesn't react well to empty braces.

Comment: I just did the same. But as my array grows in size I received "MySQL server has gone away" error. I found several solutions how to tweak MySQL to swallow such requests but I feel that this solution is not very suitable for a large arrays.

Comment: I tried this sql statement applied to the WordPress wp_users table and user_email field, with a comma delimited string of five email addresses as the list. It doesn't work, returning all email addresses. I just found out it doesn't work because the list (or if you use implode()) doesn't wrap each list item with a ' (opening and closing apostrophe). So, implode(",",$str) produces "user1@gmail.com,user2@mydomain.com,user3@mydomain.com". That fails the sql. The list has to be constructed like this: WHERE user_email NOT IN ('user1@gmail.com','user2@mydomain.com','user3@mydomain.com')";

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM main_table
 WHERE id NOT IN(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow.